# Cant add starling MovieClip to juggler on a different class

Tags: actionscript-3, movieclip, starling-framework

I guess it must be a simple answer but the truth is I've been looking trough Hsharma tutorials (part 3 starting with starling) and I can't see why my code fails to add my MovieCLip to the Juggler.

```
package
{
    import CorrePedo;

    import starling.animation.Juggler;
    import starling.core.Starling;
    import starling.display.MovieClip;
    import starling.display.Sprite;
    import starling.textures.Texture;
    import starling.textures.TextureAtlas;

    public class Heroe extends Sprite
    {

        [Embed (source = "./media/atlas.xml", mimeType="application/octet-stream")]
        //Creamos una clase para el XML
        public static const AtlasXml:Class;

        [Embed (source = "./media/atlas.png")]
        public static const AtlasTextura:Class;

        public function Heroe()
        {
            var texture:Texture = Texture.fromBitmap(new AtlasTextura());
            var xml:XML = XML(new AtlasXml());
            var atlas:TextureAtlas = new TextureAtlas (texture, xml);       

            var heroe:MovieClip = new MovieClip(atlas.getTextures("walk"), 10); 
            heroe.play();

            motor.core.Starling.juggler.add(heroe);
        }   
    }
}
```

So my starling core objest is called motor and its found in CorrePedo.as wich is the main class of my project. I get Error 1120 Access of undefined property motor. I´ve tried to create a variable who refers to the stage this way:

```
var root:MovieClip;
root =MovieClip (root);

...

root.motor.juggler.add(heroe);
```

But I guess that doesn't work.

Comment: this is not about starling you have no definiton like motor . you have to define it like
var motor:CorrePedo = CorrePedo.getInstance(); 
if you want to use singleton to reach your main class's instance. you have to know how to reach instance of your main class. btw Starling is singleton you can use Starling.current.juggler.add(heroe) if i am not wrong

Comment: You are right, I can reffer to the juggler trough Starling.current.juggler.add(heroe). Seems like I still need to work more with classes... Thanks a lot for your help

Answer (score 0):

Try `Starling.current.juggler` instead of `motor.core.Starling.juggler`